# WPF hide and show button depending on datacontext value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have 2 buttons like so:

```
<Button x:Name="button1" Content="Button 1"/>
<Button x:Name="button2" Content="Button 2"/>
```

And I have a bool variable in my DataContext named IsButton1Visible and I would like button1 to be visible and button2 to be collapsed if IsButton1Visible == true and button1 to be collapsed and button2 to be visible if IsButton1Visible == false. Is it possible to accomplish this WITHOUT using style or code-behind? XAML answers are mostly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you want to use a style? It's by far the easiest way of doing this.

One way of doing it without a style is by way of boolean-to-visibility converter i.e. something like this:

```
public class BooleanToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return false;
        var invert = (parameter == null) ? false : Boolean.Parse(parameter.ToString());
        if ((Boolean)value ^ invert)
            return Visibility.Visible;
        else
            return Visibility.Hidden;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Which you would then use like this:

```
<Button x:Name="button1" Content="Button 1" Visibility="{Binding IsButton1Visible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
<Button x:Name="button2" Content="Button 2" Visibility="{Binding IsButton1Visible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter=true}" />
```

Seriously though, just use a DataTrigger in a style to either change the visibility, or better yet, template the entire control. Converters are what you use when data has to be converted between the view and view model layers, data triggers are what you use when it's one-way only.

Comment: A trigger is the most appropriate way to do this, introducing a converter for this type of action invariably leads to short cuts and bad habits.

Comment: @slugster Agreed. The OP has specifically tagged MVVM, whenever you find yourself having to use converters to wrangle your data into something the view can work with it's usually a sign that your view model layer isn't doing its job properly.

Comment: Alright I'm gonna use a style I guess. I did not wanted to do it in first place because I end up creating tons of similar styles.

Comment: @Mr-RandomQC yes, that's pretty normal for a WPF app, but you can greatly minimize the amount of duplicated code by using the [Style.BasedOn property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.style.basedon?view=netframework-4.8) to inherit properties of other styles. Also, if you have values like certain colors etc that used throughout a lot of your styles then you can declare them as a resource and bind to them in your styles with StaticResource/DynamicResource.

Comment: I didn't know about Style.BasedOn, looks nice. Thanks @MarkFeldman!

Answer (score 1):

There is a built-in `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` that can be used to convert between a `bool` and a `Visibility`:

```
<Button x:Name="button1" Content="Button 1">
    <Button.Visibility>
        <Binding Path="IsButton1Visible">
            <Binding.Converter>
                <BooleanToVisibilityConverter />
            </Binding.Converter>
        </Binding>
    </Button.Visibility>
</Button>
```

You could define your own inverted converter and bind the `Visibility` property of the second button the same way:

```
public class BooleanToVisibilityNegationConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) =>
        (bool)value ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) =>
        ((Visibility)value) == Visibility.Visible ? false : true;
}
```

XAML:

```
<Button x:Name="button1" Content="Button 1">
    <Button.Visibility>
        <Binding Path="IsButton1Visible">
            <Binding.Converter>
                <local:BooleanToVisibilityNegationConverter />
            </Binding.Converter>
        </Binding>
    </Button.Visibility>
</Button>
```

This doesn't require any style to be defined or any code-behind to be written but it does require you to define the converter class above.

The other XAML only solution would be define an inline `Style` for the second button. This requires zero code:

```
<Button x:Name="button1" Content="Button 1">
    <Button.Visibility>
        <Binding Path="IsButton1Visible">
            <Binding.Converter>
                <BooleanToVisibilityConverter />
            </Binding.Converter>
        </Binding>
    </Button.Visibility>
</Button>

<Button x:Name="button2" Content="Button 2">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsVisible, ElementName=button1}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```